# Error running the rsim executable (Simulink Coder)

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model (2016b with MC 2013 C/C++ and Mingw-64 compilers) that I'd like to generate a standalone executable for windows-64 bit.

I was able to run the grt executable but due to the fact that I need to read a mat file runtime as opposed to compile time, I am using rsim code generation for this purpose, however the executable that gets generated appears to need quite a bit of .dll, I provided the dll it was asking for however, the application still unable to run. This is the error that results

> The application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b. Click OK to
>   close the application

What am I missing ?

Comment: Try running the exe from MATLAB using system command. The libraries may be in path if you start from MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Your main program is compiled for x64 (64-bit) target, but the dll you provided is compiled for x86 (32-bit) target. Or vice versa.

If it is Mingw-64 stuff, you should be able to obtain all (or most) of them by using the official online installer. [Link is here.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/)

Comment: I dont think that is the problem because i grabbed the dlls from the matlab directory under program files ...that is the 64 bit.